# Compartilhar repositório git local com outros usuários

Tags: git, repository

Existe algum jeito de compartilhar o meu repositório git que está no meu computador com outros usuários?

Não quero usar o GitHub, somente quero compartilhar o repositório para que o outro usuário veja o código e os commits.

Comment: se o repositório é local acredito que o único jeito seria dando acesso a outra pessoa no seu computador, se esse projeto estivesse hospedado em algum lugar você poderia dar o acesso para a pessoa ver o código e os commits, no caso de um eventual commit  e push dessa pessoa, você poderia recusar o PR (pull request) e o código e a história de commits continuaria a mesma.

Comment: Recomendo o uso do Bitbucket. É gratuito para repositórios privados e você pode compartilhá-los com outros usuários facilmente.

Answer (score 1):

Antes, é preciso compreender a diferença entre um repositório ( e uma pasta de trabalho (working directory) e um "repositório nulo" (bare repo). 
Quando você clona um repositório, ou inicia um diretório com `git init`, ele é um repositório de trabalho. Acredito que seja o que você tem na sua máquina.

Já o repositório é um pouco diferente. Você pode criar ele na sua máquina, utilizando `git init --bare`, em outra pasta. 
Resumindo, você fará todo o trabalho na pasta de trabalho, depois fará *push* ou *pull requests* para a pasta do repositório.

Quando outra pessoa quiser trabalhar no projeto, ela fará um clone do projeto em sua própria máquina, e fará *push* ou *pull requests* para a sua máquina, onde está o *bare repos*.

Uma premissa do Git é "Tudo é local". Você não compartilha o diretório de trabalho, e sim o repositório com o histórico das alterações, o bare repo.

[What is a bare git repository?](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)